# Access to setup Azure keyvault principal in Access policy

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rbac

I am trying to access key vault secret from a web activity. But I am not able to set a principle in the access policy of my vault. I have key administrator accesses. In fact I have the owner and contributor access as well. Could someone help me understand what I am missing on.[image]

Comment: Try to set the principle in the access policy using `Azure CLI` instead of the `Azure portal`.

    az keyvault set-policy --name <kvname> --object-id <service_principal_ID> --secret-permissions all

Answer (score 0):

You most likely don't have enough rights in Azure AD (Entra ID). Even if you have rights to edit the Key Vault, it doesn't mean you have rights to list users for example. You may be able to find a user in that view by typing their full username in the search field.